# Sublime Text system for Meteor

Tags: meteor, build, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I tried adding a Meteor build for Sublime Text as follow :

```
{
  "cmd": "meteor",
  "working_dir": "${project_path}",
  "shell": true
}
```

This build requires to save a file (`.sublime-project`) in the project's root folder. And it works... sort of. It just won't stop. Even closing Sublime, meteor will not stop and I have to `ps` and `kill` the process manually. I have tried the "Cancel Build" menu, and it does write `(Cancelled)`, but meteor is still running.

It is even possible to stop the build command from Sublime? Can someone share their `.sublime-build` file for meteor?

Thank you.

Comment: why do you want to use `meteor` inside a build ? It is not literally a build process. when you trigger `meteor`, it is used to start the server. Build is converting from one thing to something else rite ? I used typescript with meteor and when triggering the `build` of `sublime`, it transpile the ts file into js file, which is actually a build process

Comment: @ThaiTran perhaps my OCD talking, but it annoys me to have a terminal opened as a separate process. And since there *is* a way to execute something inside ST, I thought of using it this way. The point is still valid, though, how do you stop a working build? It clearly doesn't work as, inside a terminal, one would just send meteor a TERM signal (or CTRL+C), but it doesn't work with Sublime... so how *does* sublime "cancel" a working build anyhow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't totally agree with you on the comment section, but I think it gonna be easy to solve your problem. I have a start script to start my meteor on the server and local like this

```
# start.sh
if [ "$1" = "local" ]; then
  echo "Local mode is running"
  nohup meteor --settings config/settings.json >> log.txt 2>&1 &
else
  echo "Server mode is running"
  nohup meteor --settings config/settings.server.json >> log.txt 2>&1 &
fi

echo $! > save_pid.txt
```

and this is the stop script

```
#stop.sh
kill -9 `cat save_pid.txt`
```

Now what you need to do is making the build `start` on `Sublime` to call the start script and `cancel` to call the stop script

Comment: So... make a "variant" of the meteor build system?